How combine hair particle layers?
Please tell me how to copy hair lines in Particle edit? Ctrl+C & Shift+D don't work. Or is there no such option in Blender? Then maybe if duplicate layer & change it how need, then how then combine these 2 layers? Setting up many layers for animation is very inconvenient, so could you tell me how to combine layers with the same settings?

I think there is no such option for the (old) particle system. Which Blender version do you use? The new hair curves (Blender 3.3+) can be edited and duplicated. You also can convert particles to curves and vice versa. -- By "layers" do you mean 2 particle systems on one object?

I use v4.2 & yes, 2 particle systems on one object. I use particle system out of habit & I thought that this new Hair curves is the same thing, only more conveniently organized. And I'm not sure if it is possible to animate through Hair curves & therefore I still use particle system.
